# How to include two patterns inside one pattern?

Tags: regex, bash

**Sample Input**

`{{"access_token":"00D7F00000027wN!****.*****gIr2J3.*********","instance_url":"https://nagesingh-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com","id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D7F00000027wNUAQ/****","token_type":"Bearer","issued_at":"1537367467287","signature":"nl1tdrQ+TY64fi068KPOKGrmHf4IU3E/*****="}}`

**Sample Output**

```
pattern='"access_token":"([^"]*)"'
if [[ $response =~ $pattern ]]; then
    access_token="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    instanceFromRest="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    echo "instance is now ${instanceFromRest}"
    #uncomment to check token results
    echo "token: ${access_token}"
```

Here the instanceFromRest should return `https://nagesingh-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com`

When using `BASH_REMATCH` I would like include `instance_url` also in the pattern so that I can get `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` and get the instance_url too? 
I know the pattern for instance_url will be same as access_token, but how can I include that in the same pattern, so that I can do a `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` and get the second parameter?

```
pattern='"access_token":"([^"]*)"'
echo pattern $pattern
if [[ $response =~ $pattern ]]; then

    access_token="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    instanceFromRest="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    echo "instance is now ${instanceFromRest}"
    #uncomment to check token results
    echo "token: ${access_token}"

    echo now firing the mail url

    #now run whatever REST API query, insert, delete, etc... you want
    curl https://login.salesforce.com/services/data/v43.0/query?q=Select+Id+From+Account+LIMIT+5 -H "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" -H "X-PrettyPrint:1" 
else
    #whoops - what happened?
    echo "something went terribly wrong :("
fi
```

Comment: Could you please post sample input and sample expected output too in your post with code tags as it is not clear.

Comment: Why not use `jq` to parse JSON data?

Comment: Updated the Sample input and Sample output

Comment: Use `pattern='"access_token":"([^"]*).*"instance_url":"([^"]*)'`, see [demo online](http://rextester.com/QMYE17339).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This works, Can you please post this as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the current approach, you may just get a single match with two capturing groups:

```
pattern='"access_token":"([^"]*).*"instance_url":"([^"]*)'
                         ^^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^^
```

Note the `.*` matches any 0+ chars between the two parts of the pattern.

Upon a match, `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` will hold the `access_token` value and `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` will hold the `instanceFromRest` value.

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/QMYE17339).